# Why doesn't my Code work in Visual, but does in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, file-read

I'm trying to read some integers from a file, but in Visual Studio Code 2013 when I run it i get the error "Debug Assertion Failed! Program:...cuments\visual studio 2013\Projects....\strtol.c
Line:94
Expression:  nptr!=NULL

The same code, however, runs pretty good in CodeBlocks. I've just recently started using Visual so I'm not very good at it.
This is the content of the file I'm trying to read: 
11 7 4 1 4 0 10 12 1 3 9

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


FILE *f;
void main(void) {
    int v[30], i = 0;
    char line[30], *p;
    f = fopen("Text.txt","r");

    fgets(line, 30, f);
    p = strtok(line, " ");
    v[i] = atoi(p);
    i++;
    while (p != NULL){
        p = strtok(NULL," ");
        v[i] = atoi(p);
        i++;
    }

    int n = i-1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", v[i]);

}
```

Comment: Error checking, always error checking! What if the file couldn't be opened? What if you fail to read? What if `strtok` returns a null pointer?

Comment: If the file can't be opened, `f` could be NULL, and `strtok` may crash.  If the first line doesn't have a space, `strtok` would return NULL and `atoi` may crash.  Try stepping through the code with the Visual Studio debugger and examine the return values and see what has gone wrong.  Also do what @Someprogrammerdude suggested and check your return values in the code itself.

Comment: _Visual Studio Code_ and _Visual Studio 2013_ are not the same thing or even related. _Visual Studio Code_ does not include the Visual C++ compiler.  What compiler are you using rather then what IDE?

Comment: When this code stops in the debugger (you are running it in the debugger right?), take a look at the call stack window to determine where in your code it was before it got to `strtol()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only line likely to cause `strtol()` to be invoked is the call to `atoi()` - the call stack in the debugger will confirm that.

Both here:

```
p = strtok(line, " ");
v[i] = atoi(p);
```

and here:

```
    p = strtok(NULL," ");
    v[i] = atoi(p);
```

you fail to check `p != NULL` before passing it to `atoi()`.  From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/atoi-atoi-l-wtoi-wtoi-l?view=vs-2019):

> If the parameter passed in is NULL, the invalid parameter handler is
>   invoked, as described in [Parameter Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation?view=vs-2019). If execution is allowed
>   to continue, these functions set errno to EINVAL and return 0.

A simple reorganisation of your code will both reduce complexity *and* fix the failure to check for NULL:

```
p = strtok(line, " ");
while (p != NULL)
{
    v[i] = atoi(p);
    i++;
    p = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

The code was always wrong, but undefined behaviour is exactly that.  Both tools include a debugger, Visual Studio being the superior debugger, even if its C support is stuck in 1989.  The Call stack window will have allowed you to observe the local variables of the calling function (`main()` in this case), and you will have seen `p == NULL`.  Really; learn to use the debugger effectively - much faster than posting questions!